# Wubi is downloading file but I have full ISO

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I have "ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso" and my PC has Windows 8 installed. In my previous windows i.e "Windows 7" I used Wubi to install ubuntu 12.04.2 and installed and work correctly. Now I try to install ubuntu 12.04.2 in windows 8 using wubi, it downloads the file.

I have copied both (ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso and wubi) in the same and empty folder but it didn't work.

Specs:

- Mobo: Intel DG41WV
- HDD: Western Digital 500GB
- OS: Windows 8 Pro
- RAM: 2GB

Comment: There is no need to have the full ISO if installing through Wubi, because Wubi downloads the file by itself. There is currently no way to make Wubi make use of a self-provided ISO file that I know of.

Comment: Also, PC specs are irrelevant in this case.

Comment: There is a bug in the current 12.04.2 wubi.exe. Use this one instead and it will work: http://people.canonical.com/~evand/wubi/precise/wubi-r273-signed.exe

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to use wubi in Windows 8, so please install Ubuntu on its own partition.

See:

- [Windows installer page on ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer)
- [UEFI page on Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: But in Windows 7 with same PC specs I extracted the ISO using 7-zip. It has also a Wubi.exe and installed offline. I bought my PC on 29 Sept. 2011

Comment: @GauravKumar: Wubi is deprecated and will not be shipped any longer in 13.04. Consider dual booting in the long term.

Comment: Thanks "There is a bug in the current 12.04.2 wubi.exe. Use this one instead and it will work: people.canonical.com/~evand/wubi/precise/wubi-r273-signed.exe – bcbc"