# installing Ubuntu within Windows 7 -- where do I get the Wubi file?

Tags: software-installation

I'm using Windows 7 and trying to install Ubuntu.  The instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi#Download_Wubi) tell me

"Download Wubi from the [Ubuntu Windows Installer Download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), this will download the latest version by default."

When I follow the given link, I see the big download button that downloads an iso file.  However, I don't see where to download Wubi.

This prevents me from following the next instruction:

"Within Microsoft Windows, place your downloaded ISO in the same directory as the Wubi, and run the installer."

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  Where do I download Wubi?

Update 2: The issue mentioned in the update below is addressed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453411/ubuntu-14-04-not-booting-after-error-message-tmp-could-not-be-mounted).

Update: After reading [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/449526/305005), I downloaded wubi.exe from releases.ubuntu.com.  (Specifically I downloaded wubi.exe from the [trusty directory](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/) at releases.ubuntu.com.)  With wubi.exe now in the same directory as the ISO file ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso, I went ahead and ran wubi.exe.

Everything seemed to be going well, however, once I rebooted the computer and selected Ubuntu (rather than Windows 7), I received this error message:

[image: error message 1]

I chose "I" for "ignore", then received this error message:

[image: error message 2]

I selected "S" for "skip mounting".  Ubuntu did eventually boot up, but I had access only to a terminal and not a typical Ubuntu desktop environment.  At the terminal I did sudo reboot, which restarted my computer and allowed me to select Windows as my operating system, which still works fine.

Does anyone have any advice on how I should proceed from here?  If I restart my computer now, I'll have a choice between using Windows (which works like normal) and Ubuntu (which is currently broken).

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/294363/wubi-is-downloading-file-but-i-have-full-iso

Comment: Here's another [related answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/449526/305005) I found.

Comment: This is a new question, not information added to the original question. We try to handle questions one at a time here so that they can help as many people as possible. `cat /etc/fstab` may give some clues as to why /tmp is unavailable.

Comment: You search for answers and if not found you should open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wubi is included in  the disk image (ISO). Note that there are problems using wubi on newer hardware that has an EFI BIOS

Comment: Thanks.  How do I get Wubi out of the ISO file?

Comment: You can open an ISO with archive manager under ubuntu, you could also burn the ISO to an optical disk and copy it off of there. Which ISO did you download?

Comment: I'm currently running Windows 7, trying to install Ubuntu, and I downloaded ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso.  Since I'm using Windows 7 right now, I don't think I can use archive manager.

Comment: I know wubi.exe is in ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso. You can burn the iso to a disk using your favorite image burning program (Windows 7 I believe offers this functionality as does Nero and several other programs.

Comment: Google windows 7 open iso and you'll find http://blogs.technet.com/b/odsupport/archive/2011/04/19/how-to-extract-the-contents-from-an-iso-file-without-burning-the-iso-to-disc.aspx

Comment: I updated my question to describe a difficulty I ran into using wubi.exe -- please let me know if you have any advice!